# How to distinguish real http context or request from fake?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcontext, httpserver

We have an assembly that being called in both Web environment and Windows service. In one method it needs to investigate request. But when it runs in Windows service, we need to skip that code. I used usual method

```
if (HttpContext.Current == null)
    return;
```

But what happens, the context is not null because third party assembly somewhere within creates fake server. Hence `HttpContext.Current` contains `Server`, `Request`, etc. In quick watch it is visible that this is different kind of context. I can solve problem by doing this

```
if (HttpContext.Current == null || 
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.IndexOf("www.izenda.com",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
    return;
```

But what if next version of Izenda will have something else in the URL? What if company changes name and Url will be different?

Is there another property that can separate a real web server request or context from this fake objects?

Comment: couldn't you check current != null && "yourdomain"

Comment: @eranotzap "our domain" can be any domain. Whoever installs the product, is the owner of domain. I really don't car of domain. I only care to skip the code it this is not web

Comment: Why not add some flag to the configuration file?

Comment: If I understand correctly, then you are designing a class library that other applications use. In this case, the application should compose classes of your library in a way that it works correctly for the purpose of the application. I don't know the details about your software but code that handles the http request can be put into a separate class and then the application would decide whether to compose (i.e., wire) such class into its object graph (e.g. it would compose it if it is a web app).

Comment: @mason valid suggestion but I am not going to add yet another app setting. I wasn't the originator of that code. What I did, I refactored the code below so that I  could remove the reference to system.web completely. Question, whoever remains valid. Id about differentiating contexts. And I see some points there, such as application that runs vs no application. Different missing paths, etc. To give a definite answer, I need to try different environments. This code may run in asp.net, web api, web service, etc. on top of win service

Comment: One of the settings (items) under izenda context is izpidfromcrutchedangularpostrequestthisshouldbekilledwithfire. Translating: `iz pid from crutched angular post request this should be killed with fire`. would you believe it?

Answer (score 1):

Just put an key in appsettings in WindowsService configuration file.

```
<add key="isService" value="true"/>
```

And put a check in code to distinguish b/w web or service.

Comment: I hoped to find something better than another app setting

Comment: The good thing about the appsetting is that if in one project these are not added then their will be no exception in the application and the  code  will work as the web way. And if it does then it would go for that certain condition or vice versa.